# WPF - Passing data from DAL to UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Newb here, so please go easy....

I have a WPF project on the go, I have created a data access layer, and I get the data I require with the following code:

```
public static List<Model.CountryList> GetAllCountriesList()
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection().ConnectToBooze();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.spGetAllCountries";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var CompanyList = new List<Model.CountryList>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var Cli = new Model.CountryList();
                Cli.CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CountryID"]);
                Cli.CountryName = reader["CountryName"].ToString();
                //Add the country to Country List
                CompanyList.Add(Cli);
            }
        }
        //Return list
        return CompanyList;   
    }
```

What I am struggling with is, how do I pass this from the DAL to my presentation layer? What I had thought was to create a 'Data' class on the presentation layer, that calls the method above from my DAL and returns this list, but, I am unsure how to do this without having the 'cannot implicitly convert type list to list' error, what I had tried was:

```
  public static List<Model.CountryList> GetAllCountries()
    {     
        return DataAccessLayer.DatabaseGets.GetAllCountriesList();
    }
```

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Whatever code you have provided seems ok to me. Can you be little more specific in what error you see. Maybe post whole error ?

Comment: OK, I was an idiot. I was using a different model in my presentation layer, hence the error. Resolved it now by fully referencing the model in the DAL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Saw your comment right after posting an answer, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: As you're basically talking about Model-ViewModel communication in MVVM, I found the following search in SO helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvvm+model+to+viewmodel

Answer (score 3):

By my read your asking more about architecture than any error. With that in mind I'd say the code you provided is really part of some repository, that repository would implement an interface you've defined else where and it would be injected into any viewmodel that needs that capability.

A simplified layer diagram could be:

```
UI -> ViewModel -> Model <- DAL

namespace MyApp.Model
{
    public interface IMyRepo
    {
         IEnumerable<Model.CountryList> GetAllCountries();
    }
}

namespace MyApp.DAL
{
    public class MyRepo : IMyRepo
    {
         IEnumerable<Model.CountryList> GetAllCountries()
         {
             /**
             data access
             **/
         }
    }
}

namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
         public MainViewModel(IMyRepo repo)
         {
              this.Repo = repo;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is simply a way of separating concerns and IMHO a glorified three tiered data system.

> how do I pass this from the DAL to my presentation layer?

Place/read the data into the `VM` of the MVVM and consume it from the View which will be notified with its bound controls on the view of any loading via `INotifyPropertyChange` from the VM (*all in the background*).

See my blog article on MVVM to get you started: [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)